# Preventing duplication from SQL Query, ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have the below SQL query using the Query Builder in Visual Studio. As you can see the same user is duplicated 3 times, this is due to the user having 3 different skills. How can I merge the 3 skills together in the SQL query or in a ListView control so that it only displays one result instead of 3 and that the user has their 3 skills listed?

```
SELECT users.role_id, users.username, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.description, roles.role_id, roles.role, skills.skill_id, skills.user_id, skills.skill 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN roles ON users.role_id = roles.role_id 
INNER JOIN skills ON users.user_id = skills.user_id 
WHERE (users.role_id = 3)
```

[image: SQL Query Builder Results]

Comment: How would you like to display the data? do you want to join the three results together with comma seperator or you can display in listview in frontend.

Comment: I would like to display in listview on the frontend so that the user is only listed once, but each skill is attributed to them. So having: `Username: developertest, Skill: Skill1, Skill2, Skill3`. Currently in listiview it's listed as `Username: developertest, Skill: Skill1 | Username: developertest, Skill: Skill2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `For XML Path(''), Type`. It is a bit of a hack, because you're really creating an XML string without a root and fashioning odd elements, but it works well. Be sure to include the `Type` bit, otherwise the XML trick will attempt to convert special characters, like `<` and `&` into their XML escape sequences ([here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/80413/1) is an example).

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f293d/2) is a simplified version of your problem in a SQL Fiddle. Below is the relevant `Select` snippet.

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name, 
STUFF(
  (SELECT  ', ' + skill
        FROM skills
        WHERE users.user_id = skills.user_id 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
  , 1, 2, '') AS skill_list
FROM users
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Stuff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043(v=sql.120).aspx) and [For Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)

Here's the Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fcf71/5

See if it helps, it's just a sample so you will have to change the column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT on the Skill then group those skills into one column.
To make it simple, I test it with some sample data like the following:

```
CREATE SCHEMA _Test

CREATE TABLE _Test.SkillSet(SkillId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, SkillName NVARCHAR(64))
INSERT INTO _Test.SkillSet(SkillName) VALUES('C/C++')
INSERT INTO _Test.SkillSet(SkillName) VALUES('C#')
INSERT INTO _Test.SkillSet(SkillName) VALUES('Java')

CREATE TABLE _Test.Employees(EmpId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, FullName NVARCHAR(256))

INSERT INTO _Test.Employees(FullName) VALUES('Philip Hatt')
INSERT INTO _Test.Employees(FullName) VALUES('John Rosh')

CREATE TABLE _Test.Employee_Skill(EmpId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES _Test.Employees(EmpId), SkillId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES _Test.SkillSet(SkillId))

INSERT INTO _Test.Employee_Skill(EmpId, SkillId) VALUES(1, 1)
INSERT INTO _Test.Employee_Skill(EmpId, SkillId) VALUES(1, 2)
INSERT INTO _Test.Employee_Skill(EmpId, SkillId) VALUES(1, 3)

INSERT INTO _Test.Employee_Skill(EmpId, SkillId) VALUES(2, 2)
INSERT INTO _Test.Employee_Skill(EmpId, SkillId) VALUES(2, 3)

WITH tEmpSkill
AS
(SELECT A.EmpId, A.FullName, C.SkillName
FROM _Test.SkillSet C RIGHT JOIN
(
    _Test.Employees A LEFT JOIN _Test.Employee_Skill B
    ON A.EmpId = B.EmpId
)
ON B.SkillId = C.SkillId
)
SELECT * FROM tEmpSkill
PIVOT(COUNT(SkillName) FOR SkillName IN([C/C++], [C#], [Java])) AS Competency
```

The query above gives me an intermediate result
[PIVOT RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2uO9.jpg)

Now you can easily make a string containing all the skills needed for each employee. You can also search for some articles to use the PIVOT with unknown number of columns (skill sets), which may better serve your need.
Hope this can help.